# Reading an Excel sheet using TypeScript/React

Tags: excel, reactjs, typescript

I've been developing a Single-Page-Application using Typescript and React. I require an excel sheet to be read off. But I couldn't find a reliable source to refer to write the code for reading the Excel. 
I am aware of the xlsx Library (npm), but I couldn't get it into action. May I get help/suggestions on how to accomplish the reading task?

Comment: post some code. what do you mean you couldnt get it into action?

Answer (score 0):

According to their [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) it should be rather straightforward:

```
if(typeof require !== 'undefined') 
    XLSX = require('xlsx');
var workbook = XLSX.readFile('test.xlsx');
```

Without a little more context on what is your problem anybody can hardly give you an advice. You would need to upload the file to your server first, read it and do whatever you need to with the data. Are you looking for displaying the data on the UI as well or just process it server side?